# No CUDA runtime is found when I was installing fairseq

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, fairseq

GPU：GTX 1650

CUDA：11.7

torch.cuda.is_available() return `True`

I am trying install fairseq after cloning, but it came some problems.

when  `F:\research\fairseq>pip install --editable ./`

it showed that

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='D:\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7'
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "D:\Anaconda\envs\fairseq\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "D:\Anaconda\envs\fairseq\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "D:\Anaconda\envs\fairseq\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 144, in get_requires_for_build_editable
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\YuJie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7hnt5wal\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 446, in get_requires_for_build_editable
          return self.get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\YuJie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7hnt5wal\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\YuJie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7hnt5wal\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\YuJie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7hnt5wal\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 244, in <module>
      OSError: [WinError 1314] 客户端没有所需的特权。: '..\\examples' -> 'fairseq\\examples'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

environment variable

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also met this problem when installed fairseq,

os:win10
cuda:11.6
torch:1.12 or 1.13 both tried
gpu:2080Ti

torch.cuda.is_available() return True

I conduct this code in command line:

```
1. git clone https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq
2. cd fairseq
3. pip install --editable ./
```

It occurs problem at last and suggests me set the environment variable  SETUPTOOLS_ENABLE_FEATURES="legacy-editable"

Yet I tried and it didn't work. Thus I tried to check the pip logs and found the same problem with you. In my opinion, I think there are something wrong in build and compile, perhaps it's related to the cuda when install fairseq in windows OS

If you have solved this problem, please tell me how to fix!

Comment: while I install fairseq==0.12.2 it works

Answer (score 1):

This error message can occur if your computer machine has mulitple GPU device drivers (for ex. AMD graphic card drivers and Nivida Graphic card drivers). In this case, you must remove other graphic card drivers except Nividia Graphic card drivers (via "device manager).